# for each link change color based on array

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have an array containing the hrefs of colours and I want to go though each link in my nav and apply a different colour based on the order of the array.

I think this is possible but i'm missing something.

Here is my code

```
    var colourValue = [ "fff", "000", "FF6600", "FF00FF", "FFFF00" ];
//this is how console displays the array, I have no control over the values.
        var values = [];
        values.push(colourValue);
        console.log(values);

         $.each(values, function(index, value) { 
             var colorStyle = "#" + value +"";
             $(".nav li:first-child").find("a").css("color",colorStyle);
            });
```

Don't really know what I'm missing, Any tips? 
Thanks very much (colourValue is dynaimcally populated but for this eg I wrote it out).

Comment: is there a reason why you're taking colourValue which is an array, and pushing it into another array?..   I would think you would want to loop instead through the .nav list items.

Comment: current output would be helpful to show what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry it's my bad example basically the array contains "000", "FFF" etc so I want to take each link and apply array[1] to the first link colour, array[2] to the second link etc, the array is populated using an outside colour picker, I don't have control over it and it doesn't act like an array, hence me putting it in another. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var yourArray = ["#fff", "#000", "#FF6600", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00"];
$('.nav a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css("color", yourArray[i]);
});
```

You can really cut down the code this way, you don't need the `$.each`. Also, doing a selector the way you were is not only going to return the wrong results, but will also give you terrible performance. You were traversing the dom every time you walked through an array item. Its better to get your links first, then apply the array items to them, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

### The problems

```
var colourValue [ "#fff", "#000", "#FF6600", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00" ]
var values = [];
values.push(colourValue);
```

That's a very odd bit of code. You define an array (actually, you don't -- it's missing `=`) and give it some values, then create another array and append each of the values of the first array to the second.  You don't need two arrays here, you can just loop through the origial array.

```
var colorStyle = "#" + value +"";
```

That makes `##fff`, which is obviously not what you want.  You can just access the value with `value`.

```
$(".nav li:first-child").find("a").css("color",colorStyle);
```

This is the big problem. It loops through all the members of `values`, and on each iteration sets every link to have the colour of the current member of the array.  Your selection, however, will only ever have the links in the first `li` element, which is clearly not what you want.  You need `.nav li a`.

### The solution

jQuery has lots of nice ways of working with selections.  You probably want something like this:

```
var colourValue = [ "#fff", "#000", "#FF6600", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00" ]
$('.nav li a').css('color', function(idx) {
    return colourValue[idx % colourValue.length];
});
```

This runs a function for each element in the selection. The function receives the element's position (0-indexed) in the selection as its first argument (`idx`).  Using the modulus operator (`%`) in this way says "return 0 for the first item, 1 for the second ... 4 for the fifth, 0 for the sixth, etc".  You then use this value to find the correct colour from the array.

The return value of the function is set as the value of the CSS property.

---

A quick note to this: if you have the same number of links to be coloured as you do colours, the modulus operation is unnecessary. You could just use `return colourValue[idx];`.

Comment: first issue is the OP's selector was wrong after the first sentence of the question. She wants to apply a color to each link in nav.

Answer (score 0):

For one you are missing the "=" on var colourValue = [...

The other problem is that you are assigning the "#" to the color hex twice.

This should work:

```
var colourValues = ["#fff", "#000", "#FF6600", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00"];

$.each(colourValues, function(index, colorStyle){
   $(".nav li:first-child").find("a").css("color", colorStyle);
});
```

Comment: Seems to me this will keep overwriting the same elements color value.

Comment: Yep I'm afraid all my links are yellow atm.. :(

Comment: Woops, just versioning the OP's code without looking to the full solution, my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var colourValues = ["#fff", "#000", "#FF6600", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00"];

$.each(colourValues, function(index, value){
   $(".nav li:first-child a").eq(index).css("color", value);
});
```